# Why doesn't my css effect my django html template?

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, django

So I am trying to create navigation bar to my django template but I can't make any css adjustments. Django doesn't throw any error messages...

```
{% load static %}

<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='varaustiedot/styles.css' href="{% static 'style.css' %}"/>
    <title>Varaus</title> <! Varaus = Reserve>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <!>
        
        <!a class="active" href="home"><!/a>
        <a href="register">Varaa</a>
        <a href="#">Yhteystiedot</a>
        <a href="#">Tietoa meistä</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is my css file

```
html,
body{
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #1f2029;
}
.osoite{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
.centered-form {
    text-align: center;
 }
.topnav{
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

I tried to google the answer and I even asked chatbotGPT. So far I haven't found any issues. I have changed class names and all the names I could think of.

I had

```
?{% now "U" %}
```

when i did that link at first. But it didn't seem to do anything and every time I refreshed the site and had done some changes to css code (I checked with control + u) it had been updated...

I am not sure if there is some sort of typo or something like that but usual

```
?{% now "U" %}
```

fix didn't seem to work for me. I can try it again if it makes any difference but so far nothing.

Comment: Why do you have `type='varaustiedot/styles.css'` in your stylesheet tag? Probably should remove this attribute

Comment: I don't know about django, but remove `type='varaustiedot/styles.css'` and check if browser could find the css file, if still not working, please share your outputted page source

Answer (score 1):

loading css is a headache in django ...it saves to cache you need to empty cache and collectstatic

what i am using is

1- make a css.html with `<style> your_css </style>` tag and put the css in it

2- in the page i need the css i use the `{%include "css.html"%}` to load the css

you edit directly... no cache no `collectstatic`..nothing

Answer (score 0):

My code worked when thanks to commentors I deleted the type from my stylesheet tag.

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'style.css' %}?{% now 'U' %}"/>
```

It works now